# Import Error: No module named requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I know there are many posts on this, and I've tried using the solutions provided, but to no avail. I tried `pip install requests` and `pip install requests --upgrade`:

```
pip install requests --upgrade
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already up-to-date: requests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I then tried running `pip install --upgrade pip`, yet when I run my file I still get

```
Import Error: No module named requests
```

I am able to use requests in PyCharm, so I don't know what's causing this. Can someone please help?

Comment: reqeusts -> requests

Comment: I think you misspelled requests

Comment: There is indeed no module named `reqeusts`; you transposed the `u` and `e` (well spotted Baart).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Yes, I typed it out wrong...

Comment: @Baart yes, it was a typo, but it's not a typo in terminal

Comment: Sounds like you are running a different Python binary. What does `import sys; sys.executable` tell you you are using?

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I run that from PyCharm's concole, I get  `/Users/AlanH/anaconda/bin/python`

Comment: @AlanH: that's not the same Python executable as the Mac OS X executable (which lives in /usr/bin/python and uses `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`). You'll need to install `requests` into your Anaconda Python, or switch PyCharm to use the system Python.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90865/discussion-between-alanh-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: Out of curiosity, you don't have any virtualenv activated or messed up

Answer (score 4):

You installed `requests` into a different Python installation. The `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages` is the site-packages directory for the Mac OS X `/usr/bin/python` installation.

PyCharm is not currently configured to use that Python installation; check what Python is being used either by [looking at your PyCharm settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html), or by asking Python directly with:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Note that [PyCharm can handle package installations](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html) for you as well; rather than use the command line `pip` consider using PyCharm, as it'll use the currently configured Python installation in that case.

Answer (score 2):

install package name "request" from pychram package setting. then it will be work fine.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering an exceedingly old question that already has an answer, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster.

Comment: @nazmul that's helped

Answer (score 2):

If you are having this issue in **Pycharm** and you have configured your **Pycharm** to create projects in virtual environments, then you can use the **Terminal** in **Pycharm** to run the

```
pip3 install requests
```

to resolve this issue.  This is by design to ensure you control dependencies.