# Having trouble running Python file out of Terminal. ImportError: no module named requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I originally asked this question and took up [Martijn Pieters solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839336/import-error-no-module-named-requests)   and did as he posted:

[image]

However, I'm still unable to run my file out of Terminal. I should see files being saved in to the folder `thisdir`.

I've changed my directory to the directory of the file and I run

```
./my_file.py --todir thisdir foobar
```

But I'm still getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_file.py", line 13, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

I don't know if it matters, but I've tried running it with the first line of my file containing

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

as well as

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

I really have no idea what I'm doing here, could someone please help me through this?

---

**Update:**

I replaced the shebang in my code, and I no longer get an error, but I also don't get any output (the issue isn't a bug in the code as I tested it fully).  Here's the part of my code that requires requests

The part of my code that uses requests is below. I don't know if it

```
    for i in xrange(urls_count):
        r = requests.get(urls[i], stream=True)
        with open(save_here + '/file' + str(i), 'wb') as f_in:
            f_in.write(r.content)
```

I should see files being saved into `thisdir` and also in Terminal, a list of the newly created file's names being print out (in Terminal). So the issue isn't to add print the content (as suggested by hd1).

Also, not sure if this is relevant, but I clicked the box for "Install to user's site packages directory (/Users/AlanH/.local)

Comment: remove that line (#!/..), anaconda should handle that.

Comment: Might be due to the projects python path. Have you tried PYTHONPATH=/your/projects/main/folder python your_script.py

Comment: @Igle could you clarify? I have no idea what that means...

Comment: PYTHONPATH sets the search path for importing python modules. Make sure, requests is properly installed and in your python path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shebang line should read:

```
#!/path/to/anaconda/python
```

instead of `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/env python`.

Per your comment, the solution posted [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/how-to-download-large-file-in-python-with-requests-py) may sort you. If not, leave another comment.

You aren't printing anything to stdout from your code. The snippet below should sort that:

```
for i in xrange(urls_count):
   r = requests.get(urls[i], stream=True)
   with open(save_here + '/file' + str(i), 'wb') as f_in:
       f_in.write(req.content)
       print req.content
```

Comment: Well, now there's no error, but there's no output. I should have images pulled from websites saved to my directory, but there  aren't any images. (the error isn't the code, I've tested everything).

Comment: See my edit, @AlanH, and accept&vote up the answer if it helped you

Comment: no, it still doesn't work after setting `stream=True` =\

Comment: Edit the question, posting your complete script, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90940/discussion-between-alanh-and-hd1).