# ImportError: No module named requests (pycharm)

Tags: python, python-requests, pycharm

i'm getting troubles to use Requests on pycharm, when i write: import requests the pycharm says that there's no module named requests, but i works in IDLE Python and just in pycharm i'm getting this trouble, i'm already used the command pip install requests and upgraded for the lastest version, and it works in IDLE Python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import Error: No module named requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839336/import-error-no-module-named-requests)

Answer (score 0):

open pycharm
go to:
File > Settings > Project> Project Interpreter > Click the + button on the right side > search for "requests" module > install it